# can't find PartnerConnection and Connector Java classes

Tags: api, soap-api

I'm trying to build a simple java client program using the partner WSDL.   I build stubs from the Partner WSDL file.  I downloaded the WSC .jar file and added it to my build path.  I'm still getting Connector cannot be resolved and PartnerConnection cannot be resolved.

Anyone know where I should go for those or why I don't have them in my project when I have the stubs from the partner WSDL and the force-wsc-44.0.0.jar?

```
import com.sforce.soap.partner.*;
import com.sforce.soap.partner.sobject.*;
import com.sforce.ws.*;
import com.sforce.ws.ConnectorConfig;

class SalesforceHelper {

    public SalesforceHelper () {

        ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
        config.setUsername("username");
        config.setPassword("password");

        PartnerConnection connection = Connector.newConnection(config);
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use the maven repository for this : `https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.force.api/force-partner-api` to create a PartnerConnection

Answer (score 0):

I am sure the example in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_developer_environment_tipsheet.meta/salesforce_developer_environment_tipsheet/salesforce_developer_environment_verify_wsdl.htm) is missing something there as those classes do not exist in the client you generate from WSDL or in the wsc.jar itself.

Below is the approach, how I have used to connect using SOAP API with my Enterprise WSDL, you may just replace the enterprise package with partner package here and that should work:

```
com.sforce.soap.enterprise.Soap soap = new SoapProxy();
com.sforce.soap.enterprise.SoapBindingStub.stub = new SoapBindingStub();
com.sforce.soap.enterprise.LoginResult;
com.sforce.soap.enterprise.QueryResult qResult

loginResult; = soap.login(userName, password);
stub._setProperty(SoapBindingStub.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, loginResult.getServerUrl());
stub.setHeader("urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com", "SessionHeader", new SessionHeader(loginResult.getSessionId()));
...
...
qResult = stub.query(IConstants.query);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to connect and query but I can't get the data.  SF Docs say there's a getField() method but there ain't...

```
import com.sforce.soap.partner.*;
```

import com.sforce.soap.partner.sobject.*;

public class MyMain {

```
com.sforce.soap.partner.SoapBindingStub stub = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        MyMain helper = new MyMain();
        helper.queryContact();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(ex); 
    }
}

public MyMain() throws Exception {
    com.sforce.soap.partner.Soap soap = new SoapProxy();
    stub = new com.sforce.soap.partner.SoapBindingStub ();
    com.sforce.soap.partner.LoginResult loginResult = soap.login("zzz@zzz.com", "zzzzzzasHO9zzbYIoDH5kaujICoGBA");
    stub._setProperty(SoapBindingStub.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, loginResult.getServerUrl());
    stub.setHeader("urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com", "SessionHeader", new SessionHeader(loginResult.getSessionId()));

    //com.sforce.soap.partner.QueryResult qResult
    System.out.println(loginResult);             
}

public void queryContact() throws Exception {
    String soqlQuery = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Contact limit 1";
    QueryResult qr = stub.query(soqlQuery);
    SObject[] recordList = qr.getRecords();
    for (int i = 0; i < recordList.length; i++) {
        SObject contact = recordList[i];
        //Object firstName = contact.getField("FirstName");
        //Object lastName = contact.getField("LastName");   
        //System.out.println(firstName + " " + lastName);
        System.out.println(contact);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I believe I figured it out.  I'm so used to work in Eclipse and simply building stubs there.  SF does have a value as.  The wsc jar isn't just an add-on library, it has facilities for building value-add classes and methods.  You can't skip that step and just use Apache axis wsdl2java.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added Partner generated Stub into Project by adding external JARs from Project Properties.

I tried the same and found the Connector & PartnerConnection classes into partner stub.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer comes late, but for anyone else who might be searching for this answer. You just need to add the `force-partner-api` which a separate dependency to be able to access `PartnerConnection` -

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.force.api</groupId>
  <artifactId>force-partner-api</artifactId>
  <version>59.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```